# How to add string constant in string variables' head in C?

Tags: c

I defined a string variable by:

`char imgName[200];`

After I assign a string to `imgName`, I want to add `"C:/imgsDir"` at the head of `imgName`.

I can't determine how to do is best, and I don't want to define another string variable

Comment: There's no such thing as a *string variable* btw, that's an array of `char`. Of course, C knows *strings*, but there's no *type* for them ...

Comment: Try to use: memcpy

Comment: `char tmp[200] = "C:/imgsDir"; strcat(tmp, imgName); strcpy(imgName, tmp);`

Comment: That being said, you could use [`memmove()`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/memmove.3.html) to make room at the beginning and [`memcpy()`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/memcpy.3.html) to copy your new content there.

Comment: Can anyone say clear about using memory method..thank you..

Comment: `memmove(imgName + strlen("C:/imgsDir"), imgName, strlen(imgName) + 1); memcpy(imgName, "C:/imgsDir", strlen("C:/imgsDir"));`